# A calls B where B calls A, huge stack trace

Tags: c#, methods, stack-trace

I have a class that has two methods like this:

```
int counter = 0;

private void A ()
{
    Debug.Log (System.Environment.StackTrace);
    counter++;
    B ();
}

private void B ()
{
    counter++;

    if (counter < 100)
        A ();
}
```

This compiles and works just fine and stops after 100 iterations as expected. However, I'm a bit worried that by the end of it, the stack trace gets rather enormous.

I tried searching for this kind of pattern, but couldn't really find anything. Is doing something like this in general a no-no, or is it fine, long as it terminates properly?

EDIT: Clarification on the use of this: This is actually the main loop of my program that should keep going forever; it's not meant to be any kind of recursive function. Basically I have one big loop, but I split it up into multiple smaller methods for various reasons and they call each other in this fashion. Functionally it's the same as just having all the code in a giant while loop, but I'm worried about the stack trace.

Comment: This is how RECURSION works

Comment: This looks like quite a contrived example - recursion is a perfectly good pattern, but often it's used to deal with 'tree-shaped' problems, so the 'depth' is often only a few levels. 100 levels of recursion seems a bit heavy - even using a recursive sort on a billion data items wouldn't normally create a stack depth much over 30.

Comment: I suppose to get a feel for how much stack space you have, you could set the max iterations to 100, 1000, 10000, etc.  My guess is that the stack can get pretty big before a stack overflow.

Comment: Added an edit to clarify what I'm actually using this for; it's not really meant to be a recursive function.

Comment: You should look into Tail call and/or trampoline if you must do this and worried about the stack.

Answer (score 1):

This is a recursive pattern, and is not per se a bad design. As long as the stack generated by the recursive calls (depend on the number of calls, and the number of arguments per calls) do not exceed the maximum stack size (by default 1 MB for .NET applications), you are fine.

If it does exceed it, you would have to write the (necessarily existing) imperative equivalent.

Note:

100 functions calls is nothing compared to the stack size.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is a recursive call in two steps, is very similar to what you will do to scan a directory structure

Pseudocode:

```
Function ScanDirectory CurrentDirectory

    DirectoryList.Add CurrentDirectory

    For each Directory in CurrentDirectory

        ScanDirectory Directory
```

But a recursive function always must be very well controlled because if the recurssion does not have a limit you will get a marvelous StackOverflow exception.

Directory scanning is perfect to see those límits, the file system does not allow to have more than 256 depths, so you can be sure the recurssion limit will be 256.

If you are worried about possible overflows, then you must to implement some technique to cut the call stack, per example instead of calling directly to the methods you can add it to a work in the thread pool, in that way each call will be in a different thread and the stack will be empty in each call (that is just a really dirty example ;)  )

Answer (score 1):

This is recursion - a very common programming technique. A classic situation where different methods call each other is [recursive descent parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser): there, the stack can get pretty deep, too, when the expression being parsed has a lot of nesting.

When deciding on usability of recursion, you should consider the maximum depth of invocation in the worst case, as a function of the input size. If the function grows logarithmically, recursion is very likely to be OK. If it grows linearly, and the inputs could have several thousand items, recursion will almost certainly crash with a stack overflow.

One important exception is [tail recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call): may compilers will optimize it, letting algorithms with linear stack requirements run to completion.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call a method, that method is put onto the stack trace. This is so that when the current method returns, it knows where to go back to.

In your code example, you are calling method `A()` *recursively* as explained in other answers. If you take a close look at your stack trace, you will notice will will look something like this:

```
A() which calls...
B() which calls...
A() which calls...
B() which calls...
A() which calls...
B() which calls...
....
```

The reason for the bigger than expected stack trace is possibly because of the call to method `A()` each time method `B()` is called.

Is a big stack trace a problem? Potentially not. On a 32-bit system, the Stack Pointer is 32-bit. This means you can have a theoretic maximum of 2^32 items on your stack frame.

There is nothing wrong with recursion if used correctly. As long as you have a garenteed end clause, you are fine. In your code example, it is:

```
if (counter < 100)
```

When recursion occurs, you do need to keep in mind two things.

**Code readability**

It can be very difficult to ensure that other programmers will easily understand why the recursion is required and what is causing it. For instance, in your code example, you have method `A()` calling method `B()` which is then calling method `A()`. This is quite confusing. Typically, when using recursion, a method should call *itself*, thus creating easy to understand code. This is quite common in quick sort style functions for instance.

**Avoidance of the .NET [StackOverflowException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

It is very easy for recursion to spiral out of control and cause the above mentioned exception. For this reason, you must be able to guarantee that your end clause is solid.

In the code sample you posted, if the code was changed in method `A()` to `counter--`, you may have a problem. This is potentially a simple mistake to make as the end clause is dependent on what *other* methods are doing. Other programmers, or even yourself after a period of time, may inadvertently change this code for one reason or another. This links back to code readability. Try to keep the end clause retained to recursive itself, thus limiting this potential issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already know this. My question is, is this BAD, should I be avoiding it, and if I should, is there a good way to do that without just putting the contents of both methods into one big loop.